# Why does 1/1 time signature exist

Tags: theory, notation, time-signatures

So I stumbled around a 1/1 song like 3 days ago I still dont whats the use of 1/1, I get 2/2 and 8/8 but why does 1/1 exist?*
*Like what is its purpose?*

Comment: The real question is not "what is its purpose" (as a time signature doesn't have a "purpose") but "what requires it", which could depend on many aspects. If you can give us a reference (image, recording, or at least title/composer) to the piece you're referring to, we might try to give a more focused answer.

Comment: An example image would be helpful.

Comment: Techno time signature… 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &… not so much four on the floor as one on the floor;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, even with that techno beat, section lengths, phrasing, might suggest a meter, or meters, other than 1/1 would be sensible. `|1 & 2 &|` is not the same as `|1 & 2 & 3 &|` aren't the same simply because the drums only do `kick snare kick snare...`

Comment: @MichaelCurtis You are thinking of disco.  Techno has the same beat over and over again.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger, no, I'm not thinking of disco. Techo has phrasing. Meter isn't determined simply by a drum beat.

Comment: Is it possible there exists a song, techno or not, with no discernable phrasing over a number of measures?

Comment: The techno I'm thinking of doesn't even have a discernible kick, snare. Think of a polka, then take away the two ;)

Comment: Of course there can exists such a thing. But the point is to _look at a real case_ and determine whether it makes sense. It will certainly be odd. Both of your comments were generically about "techo" where meter 1/1 won't make sense in most cases.

Comment: Mine was a joke - gotta take these things as they're offered sometimes.

Comment: Ah, in that case: funny. But... don't quit your day job :-)

Comment: Whut?!?! I'm here all week, plus matinees!  ;))

Comment: I saw this pop up in the score of a music al once.  It screwed with many people's heads during a rehearsal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Preamble

Sometimes a piece will be conducted "in 1", the most frequent example being a piece in a fast triple meter. The conductor only indicates one beat per measure, treating what otherwise might be 3/4 as "one beat per measure, and each measure contains a triplet."

#### Examples of 1/1 used in a score

Elgar's "Enigma" variations use a 1/1 time signature for variation VII, which is in a fast (*presto*) 4. He certainly could have written it as 4/4 or 2/2 — the notation would be exactly the same — but by indicating 1/1, he's making a clear statement to the conductor and musicians about the feel: both 4/4 and 2/2 are felt as having two main pulses per measure, Elgar wants only one.

Here are the flutes, mm. 1–8, extracted from the [full score (on IMSLP)](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/1/1e/IMSLP23792-PMLP07276-Elgar_-_Enigma_Variations_(orch._score).pdf).

[image: Elgar "Enigma" variations, var. 7, mm. 1–8, flutes 1 & 2, in 1/1 time]

Borodin does the same thing for the same reason in this second symphony. Here is again the flute part from the [opening of the movement (IMSLP)](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/6/67/IMSLP197128-SIBLEY1802.10636.d603-39087009390065score.pdf), marked *prestissimo*.

[image: Borodin second symphony, mvmt 2, mm. 1-8, flutes 1–3]

#### The larger question: why 1/X?

In a sense, there's nothing special about 1/1 other than the question of "why have only one beat in a measure?"

**To reinforce the sense of a fast tempo:** as explained above.

**When an "extra" beat is needed, or beats are skipped:** In Poulenc's first Nocturne, there is a single bar of 1/2 time (m. 27). The piece is in 2/2, but this "extra" beat is needed to complete the phrase of that moment. Adding the beat to the previous bar — making a 3/2 bar — won't do, because a feeling of a downbeat is required. However, a second beat in the measure would prolong the phrase awkwardly.

[image: Poulence Nocturne #1, mm. 26-27]

#### Interesting. Tell me more.

Wikipedia has a [list of pieces with 1-based time signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_works_in_unusual_time_signatures#Upper_number_of_1).